# VBScript not pasting string values to the correct row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, qlikview

Good Day

I require help with a macro that I've setup via QlikView's VBScript functionality. I got the original code from Stefan Walther's excellent blog, http://www.qlikblog.at/971/qliktip-32-exporting-multiple-objects-single-excel-document/comment-page-1/#comments.

**Problem Statement**
After extending the code to loop through Stefan's code depending on the type of report that needs to be generated and then loops through a list of names and generates the report based on the data tied to that person.The first person's report works perfectly, but I ran into problems with the second and subsequent reports having issues where string values being pasted to multiple rows (even though only one specific cell is specified) but only for certain strings.

**What I've Tried**
1) I've tried removing my use of Range().Value to Range().Value2 and later Cell().Value.
2) Stefan already has the following in to handle timing issues with screen refresh rates when pasting in objects and dealing with warning messages:

> ```
>     Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
>       objExcelApp.Visible = False           'suppresses the display of the Excel workbook
>       objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'suppresses warning popups
> ```

and I brought in

> objExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False

just to see if it had an affect...but I would have

thought Visible = False already handles this issue.

3) I have also brought in

> ActiveDocument.GetApplication.WaitForIdle
>   ActiveDocument.GetApplication.SLEEP 3000

at different point in the script to try to avoid timing issues with the amount of content copied over thinking that the processor might be to quick (or slow) or something like that.

4) And then lastly I've gone the route of adding 
          objExcelApp.CutCopyMode = False in the hopes that it is just a full clipboard issue causing delays in pasting.

**Conclusion**
I'm not quite sure how to attach the script, but will gladly provide the code.

**Amendment**
Not sure about attaching all of the script as a text file, but here is the code snippet that export the text elements and then formats the workbook:

```html
Private Sub Excel_PopulateAdviserCommTextElements(objExcelDoc,sAdviserName,sAdviserIDNum,sAdviserEmail,sYear,sMonth,sMonthYear)
 
 sWorkbookName = sAdviserIDNum &"_"& sYear.GetContent.String &"_"&  sMonth.GetContent.String &"_"& sAdviserName 
 
 Set summarySH = objExcelDoc.Sheets("Summary")
 
 'transform the pasted objects to remove null rows and columns
 summarySH.Columns("V:V").Delete xlToLeft
 summarySH.Rows("37:37").Delete xlUp
 summarySH.Rows("71:71").Delete xlUp
 
 'replace "-" with zeroes for calculations 
    summarySH.Range("D9:V71").Replace "-", "0", xlPart, xlByRows, False, False, False 'What, Replacement, LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, SearchFormat, ReplaceFormat
        
  'calc table totals for asset table 
 summarySH.Range("V9:V37").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-18]:RC[-1])"
    summarySH.Range("D37:U37").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-28]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    'calc table totals for copmmission table 
 summarySH.Range("V43:V71").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-18]:RC[-1])"
  summarySH.Range("D71:U71").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-28]C:R[-1]C)"

 
 'add text elements
 summarySH.Cells(2,3).Value = "Wealth Solutions"
 summarySH.Cells(3,3).Value = "Monthly Commission Report: End of " & sMonthYear.GetContent.String 
 summarySH.Cells(7,2).Value = "ASSETS UNDER MANAGEMENT"
 summarySH.Cells(2,19).Value = "Commission (Ex-VAT)"
 summarySH.Cells(3,19).Value = "VAT @ 14%"
 summarySH.Cells(4,19).Value = "Amount due"
 summarySH.Cells(2,22).Value = summarySH.Cells(71,22).Value
 summarySH.Cells(3,22).Value = summarySH.Cells(71,22).Value*0.14
 summarySH.Cells(4,22).Value = "=Sum(V2:V3)"
 summarySH.Cells(41,2).Value = "COMMISSION"
 
 
 'format
    summarySH.Range("V2:V4").Style = "Comma"
    summarySH.Range("D9:V37").Style = "Comma"
    summarySH.Range("D43:V71").Style = "Comma"
    
 'emails hyperlinks
 With summarySH     'advisor email
    .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(4,4), "mailto:"&sAdviserEmail
'    .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("D4"), "mailto:"&sAdviserEmail
    .Hyperlinks(1).EmailSubject = "Monthly Solutions Commission: " & sMonthYear.GetContent.String
  .Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay= sAdviserName
 End With
 
 summarySH.Cells(75,2).Value = "Queries" 
 
 set rng = summarySH.Cells(77,2) 'commission payment email
 
  With summarySH
     .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("B77:H77"), "mailto:x@company.co.za"
     .Hyperlinks(2).EmailSubject = "Monthly Solutions Commission Payment for "& sAdviserName &" on "& sMonthYear.GetContent.String
   .Hyperlinks(2).TextToDisplay= "For queries regarding the payment of this commission please email X or phone (000) 000 0000"
  End With
  
  With rng.Font
         .ColorIndex = 0
         .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
     End With
  
     With rng.Characters(61,5).Font
         .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
         .Color = RGB(59,181,245)
     End With 
 
 set rng = summarySH.Range("B79") 'commission calc email
 
  With summarySH
     .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("B79:H79"), "mailto:y@company.co.za"
     .Hyperlinks(3).EmailSubject = "Monthly Solutions Commission Calculation for "& sAdviserName &" on "& sMonthYear.GetContent.String
   .Hyperlinks(3).TextToDisplay= "For queries regarding the calculation of this commission please email Y or phone (000) 000 0000"
  End With
  
  With rng.Font
         .ColorIndex = 0
         .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
     End With
 
     With rng.Characters(65,5).Font
         .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
         .Color = RGB(59,181,245)
     End With
    
    
 'alter column width and row height
 summarySH.Columns("A").ColumnWidth   =  4.57
 summarySH.Columns("B").ColumnWidth   = 34.00
 summarySH.Columns("C").ColumnWidth   =  0.08
 summarySH.Columns("D:U").ColumnWidth = 13.28
 summarySH.Columns("V").ColumnWidth   = 16.00
 summarySH.Columns("W").ColumnWidth   =  4.57 
 summarySH.Rows("1:1").RowHeight   = 33.00
 summarySH.Rows("7:7").RowHeight   = 23.25
 summarySH.Rows("39:39").RowHeight   = 23.25 
 summarySH.Rows("76:76").RowHeight   =  5.25
 summarySH.Rows("78:78").RowHeight   =  5.25
  
 
 'alignment
 summarySH.Range("V2:V4").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

 with summarySH.Range("B7:U7")
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  .Merge
 end with
 
 with summarySH.Range("B41:U41")
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  .Merge
 end with
 
 'hide unused columns and rows and then fill with white
    summarySH.Columns("X:XFD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 summarySH.Rows("83:1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 
 summarySH.Range("A1:W82").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 'white

 'bold
 summarySH.Range("C2:C3,R2:U4,B7,B41,B75").Font.Bold = True
 
 'lines
    With summarySH.Range("B7:V7").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With 
 
 With summarySH.Range("B41:V41").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 1
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With 
 
 'adjust focus
 'summarySH.Range("A1").Select
 
 'add filter to Consolidated sheet for Provider
 objExcelDoc.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A1:T1").AutoFilter
 
 'adjust focus
 'objExcelDoc.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A1").Select
 
End Sub
```

The particular point where things go wonky withedata applied to rows 38:41 where apply a bold and a border:

> summarySH.Cells(41,2).Value = "COMMISSION"

and rows 72:82 with following section where I add hyperlinks with email adress details:

> summarySH.Cells(75,2).Value = "Queries"

```
set rng = summarySH.Cells(77,2) 'commission payment email

    With summarySH
        .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("B77:H77"), "mailto:x@company.co.za"
        .Hyperlinks(2).EmailSubject = "Monthly Solutions Commission Payment for "& sAdviserName &" on "& sMonthYear.GetContent.String
        .Hyperlinks(2).TextToDisplay= "For queries regarding the payment of this commission please email X or phone (000) 000 0000"
    End With

    With rng.Font
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With rng.Characters(61,5).Font
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Color = RGB(59,181,245)
    End With    

set rng = summarySH.Range("B79")    'commission calc email

    With summarySH
        .Hyperlinks.Add .Range("B79:H79"), "mailto:y@company.co.za"
        .Hyperlinks(3).EmailSubject = "Monthly Solutions Commission Calculation for "& sAdviserName &" on "& sMonthYear.GetContent.String
        .Hyperlinks(3).TextToDisplay= "For queries regarding the calculation of this commission please email Y or phone (000) 000 0000"
    End With

    With rng.Font
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With rng.Characters(65,5).Font
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Color = RGB(59,181,245)
    End With
```

Thank You

Comment: could you post the script particularly the string copying and pasting in multiple row issue?

Comment: Hi ZAT, I've added the sub routine where the issue occurs, does this help?

Comment: Anything else that I can do that would help you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was rather closing the Excel workbook after producing each report and then opening up the application and then exporting and formatting the workbook for the next person, saving and closing.

Opening the workbook once, exporting, formatting, saving and closing the workbook and then looping to the next report while the application was open seemed to cause the strange exporting of elements across mutliple (or incorrect) rows